# Kill all processes from C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I am writing a Linux C program that will be executed as init. It will eventually need to shut down the system. I have code for unmounting all the filesystems and actually turning off the system; now I just need a way for it to send `SIGTERM` to all processes, `sleep(5)`, then send `SIGKILL` to any remaining processes.

Comment: *a Linux C program that will be executed as init* Are you **replacing** `init`?  It's not completely clear that's what you're doing.  If you are actually replacing `init` with your own code, it's going to need to do a lot more than what you've listed so far.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It will need to do a lot more than what I've listed in order to shutdown the system? To be specific, I am using `gdb` to make the already running init `exec()` this executable I'm writing.

Comment: You should probably checkout Torvalds GitHub for the init process: [linux init filetype:c](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+init+filetype:c).

Comment: If you're running a `systemd`-based Linux distribution, start here:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/init.1.html  and here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd `init` on such a Linux system is not a simple process.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have been looking through the `systemd` source code.

Comment: You can list the directory `/proc` to get all the process IDs, then call `kill()` to send the `SIGTERM` signal to each of them.

Comment: What's stopping you? Do you have code to send a signal to a process? Do you have code  for have code for `sleep`? Do you have code for getting a list of all processes? If yes to all of them you are done. If not, which did you answer no to?

Comment: @Broman I do not have code to get a list of processes.

Comment: @Billy So that's the actual question then? ;)

Comment: @Broman You would be right. Thanks for pointing that out. 'get list of processes in c' has much better search results than 'kill all process in c'.

Comment: @Billy Nice! It's an interesting question btw, and please answer your own question if you find an answer. But first modify your question. It's fine to mention that you want to send signals to the processes, but do also mention what your actual problem is.

Comment: If you find the answer here at SO, just flag this post as a duplicate.

Comment: @Billy If you're going to use `gdb` to force PID 1 to `exec` your code, and you're doing it on a remote system, make sure you have the ability to reboot the system without access to the OS.  Even console access may not work.  Instead of your code causing a reboot, it's possible it will just hang the system.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good to know. The worst that could happen is having to drain the device's battery so it reboots, that's why I'm using `gdb` to make the old init `exec()` my new one instead of overwriting its executable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If pid is -1:
>                If the user has super-user privileges, the signal is sent to all processes excluding system processes and the process sending the signal.  If the user is not the super
>                user, the signal is sent to all processes with the same uid as the user, excluding the process sending the signal.  No error is returned if any process could be signaled.

Using -1 for the pid will send the signal to every process that the calling process has permission for, excluding process 1, e.g.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
...
kill(-1, SIGTERM);
sleep(5);
kill(-1, SIGKILL);
```

Use with caution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going to write code to read all the numeric entries from `/proc` and go through that with `kill()`, but this is much easier.